# If $0 \leq a, b, c \leq 1$, the inequality $| a - b + c| \cdot |(a - c)^2 + b^2| \leq 1$ holds

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Please, help me to prove the inequality or find a counter-example

For $0 \leq a, b, c \leq 1$, prove that
$|a - b + c| \cdot |(a - c)^2 + b^2|  \leq 1$.

Comment: This is the second time I've seen this same question here today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $|a-c|\le 1 \implies(a-c)^2\le |a-c|$
- $b\le 1 \implies b^2\le b$

$\therefore (a-c)^2+b^2\le |a-c|+b=a-c+b=a+(b-c)$$\hspace{10mm}$(if $a\ge c$)

Now
\begin{align}
| a - b + c| \cdot |(a - c)^2 + b^2 | & = |[a - b + c] \cdot [(a - c)^2 + b^2] | \\[6pt]
& \le |[a - b + c] \cdot [a+(b-c)]| \\[6pt]
& = |[a - (b - c)] \cdot [a+(b-c)]| \\[6pt]
& = | a^2 - (b - c)^2| \\[6pt]
&\le 1 \text{ (because $a^2 \le 1;(b - c)^2\le1$ )}
\end{align}

---

Similarly, 
if $c\ge a$ we get $$ (a-c)^2+b^2\le |a-c|+b=c-a+b=c+(b-a)$$

Now
\begin{align}
| a - b + c| \cdot |(a - c)^2 + b^2 | & = |[a - b + c] \cdot [(a - c)^2 + b^2] | \\[6pt]
& \le |[a - b + c] \cdot [c+(b-a)]| \\[6pt]
& = |[c - (b - a)] \cdot [c+(b-a)]| \\[6pt]
& = | c^2 - (b - a)^2| \\[6pt]
&\le 1 \text{ (because $c^2 \le 1;(b - a)^2\le1$ )}
\end{align}

---

> $\therefore$ In any case 
>   $$|a - b + c| \cdot |(a - c)^2 + b^2| \le1$$

Comment: Often people use "|" where they should use "\mid", but this time the opposite mistake happened, and caused the spacings to be wrong in some cases (e.g. $\le\mid(a-b+\cdots$, where there is too little space between "$\le$" and the vertical slash, and too much between that and $a$; it should instead have said $\le|(a-b+\cdots$).  But your way of using \hspace to get alignments was even more unfortunate and I've fixed that too. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you very much. Brilliant proof.

Comment: Can you prove this inequality in general case?

Comment: @Vlad: what kind of generalization?

Comment: For a,b,c the determinant is going to be above expression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20028/discussion-between-vlad-and-supremum).